# Partition in fstab not showing at xfce4-places-plugin

Tags: fstab

I used **gnome-disk-utility** to edit mount options of the FAT32 formated **SDcard** in my netbook, running Xubuntu16.04. I checked *Mount at startup*, so now the SDcard is added at **/etc/fstab**. But now the SDcard disapeared from the **Places** (xfce4-places-plugin) menu at the Panel (taskbar).
 Not a big problem, it shows fine in Thunar, but I would prefere to open it directly from Places, any thought?

I also put a name at *Display Name* field, but still doesn't show at *Places*

[image: I also put a name at *Display Name* field, but still doesn't show at *Places*]

Comment: could there be a problem in 'Identify as' being /dev/mmcblk0p1? I don't think a device will be identified by the mount folder, unless you are making the mount folder the same as the real device name.

Answer (score 0):

**Mystery Solved**

The whole problem was a slash (**/**)... I was copying the partition location from the **Disks** (gnome-disk-utility), not from the **Thunar** location-bar as I should. So to have a partition both automounted (added to **fstab**) and shown at **Places** (xfce4-places-plugin), do the following:

**Copy** the partition location **with** the last slash (**/**).[image].

Open **Disks** (gnome-disk-utility) and click *Additional partition options*.[image]

Select *Edit Mount Options...*[image]

This is before any change.[image]

Set the *Automatic Mount Options* switch to the **OFF** position, check *Mount at startup* and **paste** the partitions location **with** the last slash (**/**) to the *Mount Point* field.[image]

Click OK, reboot, your **Places** panel item shows the automounted partition! Nothing scientific, just something useful for everyday use.[image]